# Getting "Behind" on a branch

Tags: api, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am currently working on a power shell script where I want to get 'behind' on a specific branch

`"$(System.TeamFoundationCollectionUri)$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/git/repositories/$(Build.Repository.ID)/stats/branches?name=$(Build.SourceBranchName)&api-version=6.0"`

This works fine on branches Main, develop, and on any branches that are present in refs/heads/<branch_name>

but I continuously receiving error "**the $(Build.SourceBranchName) does not exist on $(Build.Repository.ID)**" whenever a branch is created on,
for example ***refs/heads/feature/<branch_name>***

'

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [definition of the `Build.SourceBranchName` predefined variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#build-variables-devops-services), I can make an assumption that it is set by the system the first time that branch is actually built.

> Build.SourceBranchName: The name of the branch in the triggering repo the build was queued for.

This explains why the API request you mentioned in your question works for older branches but does not work for a newly created branch. Try building that branch and then run that request again to verify this assumption.